# be seen -ing vs. be seen to be -ing

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference in meaning between the two, for example, between ***They are seen smoking cigarettes.*** and ***They are seen to be smoking cigarettes.***?

Answer (score 3):

They are different. One uses a verb; the other uses an idiomatic verb phrase.

- '*Seen*' refers purely to the act of perceiving something with the eyes. If someone says "*I saw you smoking*" it means they personally observed you doing this.
- '*Seen to be...*" has a more idiomatic meaning. It refers to how something is *perceived and understood*. For example, if, someone said "*you must be seen to be working hard*" the implication is that you must act in such a way that it *looks like* you are working hard. That might mean exaggerating your movements, and making sure that there is evidence of your hard work. It can involve more than just visual perception, but an awareness that comes from all senses.

I don't think 'seen to be' is necessary in your example - if you observe someone smoking, you *saw* them and it is no more complex than that.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that "seen to be" doesn't work very well with verbs. It's great for qualities and attributes: "He's seen to be honorable." You can even make attributes out of verbs: "seen to be hard-working." But while "You must be seen to be working hard" isn't so unreasonable as to object to, it would be more comfortable as just "seen working hard," if it means that your actual act of working should be observed, or "seen to be hard-working" if it means a habitual pattern.